# Checking if mysql_query returned anything or not

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

If 'table' has no rows. whats the easiest way to check for this.?

Comment: I assume that this is PHP?  I've changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: Try `if (!isset($result)) { // nothing has been returned } `.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [mysql_num_rows($results)](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) to check if 0 rows were returned, or use this faster alternative:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
$num_rows = $values['total'];
```

Comment: If you *want* to get data from the table, but just want to know if it's empty so that you can say so on the results page, then do your normal query and use mysql_num_rows. What you don't want to do is: count the rows (using the above), then do the normal query if count > 0.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking of that because I usually do the "SELECT COUNT(*)" query to calculate the number of pages of content, then SELECT just a few rows from the table depending on what page of content the user is on.

Comment: `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 33):

Jeremy Ruten's answer above is good and executes quickly; on the other hand, it only gives you the number of rows and nothing else (if you want the result data, you have to query the database again). What I use:

```
// only ask for the columns that interest you (SELECT * can slow down the query)
$query = "SELECT some_column, some_other_column, yet_another_column FROM `table`";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$numResults = mysql_num_rows($results);
if ($numResults > 0) {
   // there are some results, retrieve them normally (e.g. with mysql_fetch_assoc())
} else {
   // no data from query, react accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can simply check if the result of mysql_fetch_assoc is false.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
if ($Row == false)
{
  $Msg = 'Table is empty';
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the best answer since all that needs to be done is check if mysql_fetch_assoc of the query produces something that is not null

Comment: why do you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `$Row = $result->fetch_assoc();` any difference?

Comment: This is a very old post.  I now use Laravel. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing i noticed that was missed was the fact that the query might not succeed, so you do need to check if the $results variable is set. I'll use the answer given by yjerem as an example.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if ($results) { // or use isset($results)
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
$num_rows = $values['total'];
}
```

Answer (score -6):

If you loop through the results, you can have a counter and check that.

```
$x = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $x++;
}
if($x == 1)
{
  //No rows
}
```

Comment: no it wouldn't. array("") == true. This is still a very silly way to check it though.